# Google OAuth 2.0 Flow Issue (Implicit)

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-web-api, oauth, google-oauth

I have reading and reading for months on all of this and for some reason, it's just not clicking. I have a RESTful web API written in .NET living at api.domain.com  and the site, domain.com is an AngularJS SPA app.

If there is no access_token on the client (localStorage), I redirect the user to Google to authenticate via OAuth 2 and they are redirected back to a callback page where I write the access_token to local storage.

What I'm struggling with now is, when I make a call to the API and send that Bearer token, how do I get my API to recognize it and authenticate the user so that I can call Authorized methods??

I think I'm running in circles here and just need some solid direction.

Authentication Endpoint: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
Scopes: openid profile email
Redirect (for now): http://localhost/callback.html
Web API: http://api.domain.com
Flow: Implicit Flow
SPA: http://localhost
Token Validation URI: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo

User comes into http://localhost, angular app checks for access_token in local storage. If one is detected, it makes a call to token validation URI to ensure that it is valid and not expired. In angular, via http interceptor, any request that goes out that's URI is to the Web API, it sets the access_token as a bearer token on the authorization header.

What I expect to happen at this point is that any api methods I have marked as Authorize, it will now allow through with the User.Identity object now hydrated and return a 200.

Comment: I think you are confused about something.  Can you give me a little more detail in what you are doing.  which api are you trying to call?

Comment: I am very confused. Every time I think I get it, I clearly don't. I want to take the access_token that I got from Google and be able to use it to authorize a user in the API to determine if they have access or not. I want to do that through the api that I wrote living at api.domain.com.

Comment: You want to use a Google access token to see if someone can have access to an api you wrote?  Do I really want to know why you would want to do that?   Google access tokens are for getting access to Googles APIs what scope are you even sending?

Comment: Wait. I think I explained incorrectly. I set up a new App through the Google developer console in which they issued me a api key and secret. When the user comes to the site (again, angularjs and implicit flow), if there is no access token, they get redirected to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=token&client_id=<key ere>&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback.html&scope=profile email openid&prompt=select_account. Once they get sent to the callback with the access_token, I write that token to localStorage and consider them authenticated.

Comment: When API calls are made from the client, I will send that access_token in the authorization header as a bearer token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wonderful presentation located here.

https://speakerdeck.com/developerinfra/authentication-using-tokens-for-angularjs-owin-asp-dot-net-web-api-and-identity

And this awesome article located here.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Paired with his most excellent sample implementation located here.

https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication

After one of the longest research efforts in my 17 year career, I found the one guy who put it all together.